# Wrong vim colors in iTerm2

Tags: macos, vim, color-scheme, iterm2

First of all, sorry if this is another one of those vim colors in iTerm2 questions. I have tried everything I could find and still can't solve the issue. iTerm2 just doesn't give the correct colors for me. Here is a screenshot comparing iTerm2 vim to Macvim.

[image]

`:echo &t_Co` gives me `256`.

iTerm2 report terminal type is set to `xterm-256color`. `echo $TERM` gives `xterm-256color`.

I am using base16-solarized as my colorscheme. The iTerm2 colorscheme is [this](https://github.com/chriskempson/base16-iterm2/blob/master/base16-solarized.light.256.itermcolors), and my vim colorscheme is [this](https://github.com/chriskempson/base16-vim/blob/master/colors/base16-solarized.vim).

Here is my [vimrc](https://github.com/keithyong/dotfiles/blob/master/vimrc).

Thanks for the help

edit: Here is another comparison, this time using the solarized.vim color from [altercation/vim-colors-solarized](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized):
[image]

edit: Tried with $TERM set to xterm, colors are better but there are still some issues with the buffer airline bar, not sure if this is supposed to be normal

[image]

Comment: The whole point of setting your `TERM` to `xterm-256color` is to allow Vim to use colors 16 to 255 of the xterm palette. `xterm-256color` is pointless — in your situation — because neither Base16 nor Solarized use any color from that palette.

Comment: Tried with $TERM set to xterm, colors are better but there are still some issues with the buffer airline bar, not sure if this is supposed to be normal

Answer (score 1):

[As mentioned](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized#important-note-for-terminal-users) on the vim-colors-solarized Github page, to get the correct colors in your terminal emulator you should change the default colors of iTerm2.

To do so simply follow the instructions [given here](https://github.com/chriskempson/base16-iterm2) for the base16-solarized.light colorscheme.

Comment: I have both iterm and vim set to base16-solarized light non-256 on that original picture

Comment: In your last comment you mention that you are using the _non-256_ itermcolors. However, in your original question you provide a link to the itermcolor-presets you currently use which _do have_ 256 colors. So please make sure you really use the non-256 itermcolors-preset (there are two variants).
Besides advising you to better use altercation's vim-colors-solarized plugin I don't know what else you could try.

Comment: I have tried both base16-iterm-solarizedlight on 256/non-256 variants and that didn't fix the issue for me

Comment: I guess setting `let g:solarized_termcolors=16` and `let g:solarized_termtrans=1` in your `.vimrc` will not change something either as those should be the default settings, but you could try that as well. Other than that I am sorry, I have no more ideas :(

Comment: Thanks for your help :) Since my bounty is ending soon anyway you can have it.

Comment: Thank you, but I feel I should not receive it as I was not able to solve your problem. Is there a way I can transfer it back to you?

Comment: Not that I know of. Not a big deal though, enjoy your free bounty I guess. The rep that I put up for the bounty was gonna disappear anyway, so I might as well hand it out to you for helping me out.